# How to extract acroFormType for each field using PDFbox

Tags: kotlin, pdfbox

I have created a primary function that imports an inputStream (which in this case will be a file from my local). In this second function, I want to import the acroFormType of the interactive fields of the entered pdf, but when I try to access the type, a null value appears, since the field values are entered as follows:
field = {PDPushButton@3993}"nullstill{type: PDPushButton value: null}"

The result is that it returns the name correctly but not the type, the way I get it in the function. It must be taken into account that value is null, and I don't know if that value could be causing the error...

```
fun pdfFieldDefinition(interactiveFields: MutableMap<String, PDField>): PDFFormDefinition {

    // Create an empty mutable list, in which we will then introduce the field objects
    val resultList = mutableListOf<MyInteractiveField>()

    // Iterate over each of the interactive fields in the list and introduce the type of each of them in a new variable based on its acroForm type
    interactiveFields.forEach { (name, field) ->
      
      val fieldType = FieldAcromType.from(field.fieldType.toString())
      println("Field name: $name, Field type: ${field.fieldType}")


      // If the type of field is valid, obtain its value
      if (fieldType != null) {...}
```

I want to obtain the acrofromType of each one of the interactive cells, to create an object with each one of them and introduce it in a list that the function will return.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"the acroFormType of the interactive fields of the entered pdf"*?

Comment: I mean how to extract the type of each interactive field, if it is of type text, checkbox, pushbutton...

Comment: I already know why the null value was happening, because I generated an enum class with values that did not match the eigenvalues of the cell type in pdfbox. For example, in my enum class I had TEXT added, but that value came to my pdf code as TX, and that's why it was always null, just look for the abbreviations in the documentation and that's it!

Comment: why not get the class? Btw what programming language is this?

Comment: *"I already know why the null value was happening, ..."* - so your issue is resolved? Then you might want to post the solution as an actual answer (not a mere comment).

Comment: Because it is an enum class, so i cant instance the class. So since the only thing I wanted was to make my own enum class, I looked at the values and added them (but incorrectly as I already commented). The language is kotlin. By the way, thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

I already know why the null value was happening, because I generated an enum class with values that did not match the eigenvalues of the cell type in pdfbox. For example, in my enum class I had TEXT added, but that value came to my pdf code as TX, and that's why it was always null, just look for the abbreviations in the documentation and that's it